# Pass inputText as f:param on button click

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

So, I have this jsf code

```
<h:inputText id="serviceId"/>
<h:commandButton value="Enter" action="agreementDetail.xhtml"/>
```

I need to send the customer's input in the serviceId field as a f:param to the next page (agreementDetail.xhtml). So, the customer inputs the value, clicks on the "Enter" button, and the next page receives the inputted value as a parameter.

Comment: All parameters should be parsed by framework and populated the bean upon request.

Comment: I'm not using beans to pass these parameters. If possible, I'd like to know if I can use the f:param to pass the input value between pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a regular GET form with a regular HTML button instead. JSF as being a POST form oriented framework offers no advantages for you here, so there's not really a point of using a JSF component here.

```html
<form action="agreementDetail.xhtml">
    <input name="serviceId" />
    <input type="submit" value="Enter" />
</form>
```

For the case you didn't already know that, you can in the target view `agreementDetail.xhtml` use `<f:viewParam>` to process the GET request parameter and set it as a bean property like as if it's a `<h:inputText>`. See also [What can <f:metadata>, <f:viewParam> and <f:viewAction> be used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377798/what-can-fmetadata-and-fviewparam-be-used-for/)